# A New Angle and a Plug

Tags: wordplay, visual

Your task remains the same as before - each ellipse represents an as-yet unknown category and each of the tiles belongs in at least one category. Two are placed to help you.  Your question is which tiles go where and why?

[image]

Comment: Nice work on the Alex Bellos feature!

Comment: Thanks - he's a good chap!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this Venn diagram should be resolved as follows:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

Where the two ellipses represent:

> **Left:** Words which can be affixed to a **fruit** to form a real word:
>
>  PINE**APPLE**, CANDI**DATE**, **GRAPE**FRUIT, DISAP**PEAR**, **PLUM**METING
>
>  **Right**: Words which can be affixed to a **geometric object** to form a real word:
>
>  HARPSI**CHORD**, PINE**CONE**, **DISC**OVERER, BEE**LINE**, TRAMPO**LINE**, DISAP**POINT**
>
>  'DISAP' and 'PINE' thus appear in the intersection between the two.

Note then that the title:

> mentions '**angle**' - another geometric feature, and hence a clue... (and you can also affix ['banana' to 'plug'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector)!)

Comment: Wow - that's quick and right!  (Though you might be slightly out on one small point!)

Comment: rot13(QVFNC pna nyfb unir CBVAG)

Comment: Ha, thanks - I'd even thought of that one and ruled it out, totally forgetting its relevance to that other category! Will fix...